# Which function grows faster, exponential or factorial?

Tags: factorial, exponential

Which function grows faster, exponential (like 2^n, n^n, e^n etc) or factorial (n!)? 
Ps: I just read somewhere, n! grows faster than 2^n.

Comment: Q: Why don't you try it?  With a program, or simply look at a series of a few numbers?  You'll find the answer in less time than it took to ask this question ;)

Comment: wanna see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D2%5Ex%2C+y%3Dx%5E2%2C+y%3Dx%21)?

Comment: @paulsm4, I already tried with simple excel. But, unfortunately I couldn't go more than 144 (ie., 144^144) due to overflow. Hence I thought to ask some theoretical proof for the same.

Comment: @paulsm4 It's not so simple as just trying it.  Curves can be deceptive.  The result depends on the coefficient, and the crossover point may be difficult to find.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: @AlvinWong, How do we make the graph extend beyond `x=2`?

Comment: Here's this question with some formulas: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351815/do-factorials-really-grow-faster-than-exponential-functions

Comment: @PeterMajeed I suppose you're right, but I interpreted it as referring to the running time of algorithms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. It would be better suited on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 186, accepted):

n! eventually grows faster than an exponential with a constant base (2^n and e^n), but n^n grows faster than n! since the base grows as n increases.

Comment: You're correct: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: @Glen, Is there a name for `n^n`?

Comment: @Pacerier a name for n^n is superexponential

Comment: How much faster? :)

Comment: @paulsm4 That question doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: @Glen @Pacerier Also relevant, `n^n^n...^n` is called a power-tower, or [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) ([along the same lines as addition, multiplication and exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation)). So `n^n` can be said somewhat more trivially as `n` _tetrated by_ 2.

Comment: In fact, n! grows asymptotically exactly like n^n, as seen by Sterling's formula: $n! \simeq \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$. Both are superexponential, as no exponential with a constant base can grow this fast.

Answer (score 138):

`n! = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ...`

`n^n = n * n * n * ...`

Every term after the first one in `n^n` is larger, so n^n will grow faster.

Comment: could not be explained simpler than this.

Comment: same comment as @sn.anurag ,  i like your simple explanation, simple and powerful :)

Comment: This answer is useful, but it could be improved by doing something similar to compare `n!` and `2^n` (and that reasoning would extend to any constant base).

Comment: every term of `n+1` is larger than `n`, but it doesn't grow faster :)

Comment: This is not quite right. Yes, n^n is larger than n!, but that's not usually what we mean when we talk about growth rates. By Sterling's formula, n! and n^n are asymptotically equivalent up to a constant scaling: n! approaches \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n as n grows.

Answer (score 6):

`n^n` grows larger than `n!` -- for an excellent explanation, see the answer by @AlexQueue.

For the other cases, read on:

Factorial functions do asymptotically grow larger than exponential functions, but it isn't immediately clear when the difference begins. For example, for `n=5` and `k=10`, the factorial `5!=120` is still smaller than `10^5=10000`. To find when factorial functions begin to grow larger, we have to do some quick mathematical analysis.

We use Stirling's formula and basic logarithm manipulation:

```
log_k(n!) ~ n*log_k(n) - n*log_k(e)

k^n = n!
log_k(k^n) = log_k(n!)
n*log_k(k) = log_k(n!)
n = log_k(n!)

n ~ n*log_k(n) - n*log_k(e)
1 ~ log_k(n) - log_k(e)
log_k(n) - log_k(e) - 1 ~ 0
log_k(n) - log_k(e) - log_k(k) ~ 0
log_k(n/(e*k)) ~ 0

n/(e*k) ~ 1
n ~ e*k
```

Thus, once `n` reaches almost 3 times the size of `k`, factorial functions will begin to grow larger than exponential functions. For most real-world scenarios, we will be using large values of `n` and small values of `k`, so in practice, we can assume that factorial functions are strictly larger than exponential functions.

Answer (score 4):

I want to show you a more graphical method to very easily prove this. We're going to use division to graph a function, and it will show us this very easily.

Let's use a basic and boring division function to explain a property of division.

[image: division with variables a and b]

As a increases, the evaluation of that expression also increases. As a decreases, the evaluation of that expression also decreases.

Using this idea, we can plot a graph based on what we expect to increase, and expect to decrease, and make a comparision as to which increases faster.

In our case, we want to know whether exponential functions will grow faster than factorials, or vice versa. We have two cases, a constant to a variable exponent vs. a variable factorial, and a variable to a variable exponent vs a variable factorial.

Graphing these tools with Desmos (no affiliation, it's just a nice tool), shows us this:

#### Graph of a constant to variable exponent, vs variable factorial

[image: graph 1]

Although it initially seems that the exponential expression increases faster, it hits a point where it no longer increases as fast, and instead, the factorial expression is increasing faster.

#### Graph of a variable to variable exponent, vs variable factorial

[image: graph 2]

Although it initially seems to be slower, it begins to rise rapidly past that point, therefore we can conclude that the exponential must be increasing faster than the factorial.

Comment: Note: `a/b` will tend to infinity if `a` grows faster than `b` and it will tend to `0` if `b` grows faster than `a` (and it will tend to a constant if they grow at the same rate).

Comment: >As b decreases, the evaluation of that expression also decreases.

This is a false statement. As b decreases, the evaluation of the expression increases. Aside from that I like the explanation.

Comment: good catch, im surprised nobody else commented on it